# Setting up SimpleModal in a Rails Project

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I am using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to create a pop-up view when I click on an image. The view will contain a bigger version of the image as well as some other populated data for that image.

The problem is that I am a bit confused with the documentation and I'm fairly new to jQuery/JS.

I assume that we're creating a hidden div with all the information we want to pop up on the index page.

layouts/application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.photo_container').click(function(e){
            $('#basic_modal').modal();
        });
    });​

  </script>
</head>
```

photo/index.html.erb

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>

  <div class="photo_container">
    <%= image_tag photo.url %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div id="basic_modal">
  <p>This is the sample pop up page that will display a bigger image and info.</p>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that a modal pops up when I click on the image?

Edit: I tried moving the script to right before my closing body tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery(function () {` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Give your images a class, for example, `photo_container`.

Then bind the click to make it open a modal:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.photo_container').click(function(e){
        $('#basic_modal').modal();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Do I have to add a link_to tag anywhere? I placed your code between an opening and closing script tag, but I cannot click on the image to display the modal still.

Comment: Apologies, i had a typo in the code. (basic-modal instead of basic_modal)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your app is loading the SimpleModal js file?  The .js file for it is in vendor/assets/javascripts and it has a line in the application.js file for the asset pipeline to pick up?